# How do you derive the soft iron matrix for magnetometer calibration?

Tags: imu, magnetometer

Can someone send reliable sources for how this is derived? I understand the diagonal values are for scale, but how do you determine all 6 values needed for this matrix? I would also like to normalize the radius to 1 while doing so. I've found many papers of ellipsoid fitting, but am unsure of how to translate this for my use, and honestly could just use some outside input.